# when i update UIMap in coded UI test , the UIMap.Designer.cs file overwrite on my code

Tags: automation, coded-ui-tests

when i record a test method for "Login Scenario" with Coded UI test , it generates code like this

**Generated Code**

```
        public void LoginMethod()
    {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinEdit uIItemEdit = this.UIDiagnosoftVIRTUEWindow.UIItemWindow.UIItemEdit;
        WinEdit uIItemEdit1 = this.UIDiagnosoftVIRTUEWindow.UIItemWindow1.UIItemEdit;
        WinComboBox uIItemComboBox = this.UIDiagnosoftVIRTUEWindow.UIItemWindow2.UIItemComboBox;
        WinButton uIConnectButton = this.UIDiagnosoftVIRTUEWindow.UIConnectWindow.UIConnectButton;
        #endregion

        // Type 'username' in 'Unknown Name' text box
        uIItemEdit.Text = this.LoginMethodParams.UIItemEditText;



        // Type '********' in 'Unknown Name' text box
        Keyboard.SendKeys(uIItemEdit1, this.LoginMethodParams.UIItemEditSendKeys1, true);

        // Select 'facility' in 'Unknown Name' combo box
        uIItemComboBox.SelectedItem = this.LoginMethodParams.UIItemComboBoxSelectedItem;

        // Click 'Connect' button
        Mouse.Click(uIConnectButton, new Point(64, 14));
    }
```

i update this code to allow Data Driven Source ,CSV file which contains username,password,....
here is the updated code

**Updated Code**

```
      public void LoginMethod(string username,string password,string facility)
       {
        #region Variable Declarations
        WinEdit uIItemEdit = this.UIDiagnosoftVIRTUEWindow.UIItemWindow.UIItemEdit;
        WinEdit uIItemEdit1 = this.UIDiagnosoftVIRTUEWindow.UIItemWindow1.UIItemEdit;
        WinComboBox uIItemComboBox = this.UIDiagnosoftVIRTUEWindow.UIItemWindow2.UIItemComboBox;
        WinButton uIConnectButton = this.UIDiagnosoftVIRTUEWindow.UIConnectWindow.UIConnectButton;
        #endregion

        // Type 'msameeh' in 'Unknown Name' text box
        uIItemEdit.Text = username;

        // Type '{Tab}' in 'Unknown Name' text box
       uIItemEdit.Text=password;


        // Select 'diagnosoft.com' in 'Unknown Name' combo box
       uIItemComboBox.SelectedItem = facility;

        // Click 'Connect' button
        Mouse.Click(uIConnectButton, new Point(64, 14));
    }
```

and i run test method and it works well But when i edit the UIMap to add unused controls like "Canncel button" or any other controls 
like in this link

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shair/archive/2010/08/08/coded-ui-test-tip-4-add-unused-controls-to-ui-map.aspx
the UIMap.Designer.CS file overwrites my Login method **Updated code** with **Genereated code**

Thanks in Advance

Comment: i found an easy solution for copying methods form UIMap.Designer.cs to UIMap.cs

1- Feature Pack2 must be installed 
2- open UIMap.uitest 
3- write click on method that you want to update its behavior and select "Move code "
Result : 
Method will be moved from UIMap.Designer.cs to UIMap.cs

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should not edit the *UIMap.Designer.cs files.  Those are auto generated.  That is the purpose of the *UIMap.cs file, for your custom methods and implementations that will not get overridden.

That is why the comment block at the top of the Designer files states not to edit them manually.

Comment: this should be marked the answer for the question, not the one above, that is totally wrong. DO NOT EDIT AUTOGENERATED CODE. That's the only valid rule.